# Add tooltip permanently on particular svg in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to add a tooltip to a funnel chart which is made of svg. I want the tooltip to be static and it should be shown while the chart is loaded and it should stay on the graph statically. It has to look something like this
[image]

I've tried something:

```
var tip = d3.tip()
        .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
        .html(function (d) {
        return '<table style="width:100px"><tr><td style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold"> ' + d.ind + '</td></tr><tr><td style="font-size:10px">Total Cases:</td></tr><tr><td font-weight-800" style="font-size:12px; color: #2B597C; font-weight: bold" >' + d.tot_cases + '</td></tr></table>'
            ;
        })
    svg.call(tip);
        g.append("polygon")
            .attr("points", points.map(function (d) { return [d.x, d.y].join(","); }).join(" "))
            .attr("stroke", "white")
            .attr("stroke-width", 1)
            .attr('fill', function () { return (color2[i]) })
            .each(function(){
                 if (data[i].ind == "Notified") {
                 // tip.style('top', (event.pageY) + 500 + "px");
                 // tip.style('left', (event.pageX) + 30+ "px");
                tip.show(data[i], this);
        }
      })
```

I'm not getting the tip in correct position. I've changed the cooridinates but it is not working. It is showing like this:
[image]
Any ideas on how to make it look static without mouseover or hover.
 My entire code is in [here](https://codepen.io/wittybutterfly/pen/eYmaopg)

Comment: What do you mean by static? where do you want it to be positioned?

Comment: It should be fixed not on mouseover or hover or click. It should be positioned as shown in the first image @Ma’moun othman